# How to force Eclipse to see java project as java project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, project

I have downloaded a 3rd party project, which consists of multiple files, including Java ones.

General structure is as follows:

```
<topfolder>
   pom.xml
   <subfolder1>
      pom.xml
      src
         main
            java
               <normalclasspath>
            resources
         site
            apt
               index.apt
         test
            java
               <normalclasspath>
```

Eclipse imports this project normally, but is unable to index its Java content. For example, I can't browse from a variable to its definition, and so on.

Also I can't set my own `Build Path` since it says `No action available`.

Of course, I can refactor folder structure myself to suite eclipse needs, but are there any automation means for this?

**UPDATE**

Yes, this is a Maven project and Eclipse already knows that it has Maven nature. The only option now is to disable it

[image]

But this is not a question. The question is how to add **JAVA NATURE**, so that Eclipse knows consistence of classpath and be able to navigate to class definitions and so on.

**UPDATE 2**

@75inchpianist's answer about facets helped partially. It was not available to select Java facet immediately, but required turning on facets at all first. Then Java facet was already there.

Now I see, that Eclipse interprets Java, but Maven interpretation is not full. Namely, no Maven dependencies interpreted (no `Maven Dependencies` node in `Package Explorer`).

The attempt to add it fails:

[image]

Comment: This is a `maven` project, you need to have the maven plugins installed.

Comment: You can probably get eclipse to recognize it by modifying your .classpath and .project files after you imported it into eclipse. Alternately, you can likely use the eclipse project preferences window to add the java directories as src folders.  ... Also, what method did you use to import the project?

Answer (score 6):

Right click on the project and select "Properties"

Within "Project Facets" make sure that Java is selected!

Answer (score 4):

As this is a maven project (because of the pom.xml) you need to install a maven plugin for eclipse. 
Next you have to right click on the project and choose "Configure->Convert to Maven Project".

Now you should have your normal java structure.

Comment: This is the only valid answer so far

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Eclipse recognizes the project as Java project yu can do the following:

If you don't want to install a maven plugin into Eclipse you can make Eclipse recognize the source correctly by adding every `src/main/java` folder as Source-Folder to your Build-Path.

This is better than modifying the folder structure as you can update the sources without problem later.

Answer (score 0):

Add following to your **.project** file and refresh the project.

```
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
</natures>
```